# Problem with normal map and Cycles rendering

Tags: normal-map

I have a stairwell designed. There are several point lights. On the steps and treads (on all faces is laid a concrete texture : color map + normal map. In Eevee everything is ok. But with Cycles, the lights on these planes are for some reason dependent on the viewing direction. When I look straight ahead or down, everything is OK. As I lower the viewpoint and start looking up, some planes get dark, and at high viewing angles, black. The "fault" is on the normal map side. If I disconnect the "normal map" node, everything goes back to normal, but I don't get the effect of uneven concrete. The situation also changes depending on the settings in the "normal maps" node: Space (here, when changing the space, black fields appear on other faces) and Strength (here, the darkening disappears only when the value is 0). I have other objects (walls with plaster) for which nodes and maps are constructed identically and this problem does not occur there.  Hmm ... how to fix it ?
[image: black faces]
[image: nodes]

Comment: A normal map strength that high is perturbing the normals to the point they can't even be rendered as facing the camera, so the rays are lost.  At least that's my interpretation.

Comment: I would also suggest lowering the strength, I actually never ever go above 1. Usually I stay below 0.5, if you need really uneven surfaces you should go for displacement. But I don't think a staircase is made out of cobblestones.

Comment: At a strength of less than 4 the irregularities of the concrete surface are not visible. My plaster has a strength of 5 and is perfect. Also, when I look at the top surfaces of the stairs, this problem is not there even by strength 10. All normal maps are loaded from a reputable source and they are correct. Additional light sourcess.placed near the black areas does not help.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using world space for your normal map - tangent is more likely to work for you.

Comment: At the tangent setting, the black spots disappear. The disadvantage is that even at a strength of 10 the effect is almost invisible. Maybe the original normal map is too soft ?

Comment: This might well be. Your normal map might come from a "reputable source" but I'm not sure if that means they are perfect. Since the normal map is not used to create real displaced geometry, no matter how high you set the strength it will still be a flat surface. And the higher the strength the more problems it will generate especially at certain angles. I think even 2 would be far too much. So maybe your normal map isn't using the full color range and needs to be normalized in some way.

Comment: I have created a Normalmap using a Gimp add-on filter called Normalmap. It makes this map from Color Map. I have increased Scaling (equivalent to Strength) 40x. Now the unevenness effect is very strong, I was able to decrease the Strenght to 4. The visibility on different planes is of course also dependent on the angle of the light rays, so it's still poorly visible in some places, but that's how it should be. Simply increasing the contrast of the original Normal Map gives unacceptable significant errors.

Comment: Here are original maps I use:  https://cc0textures.com/view?id=Concrete029